How to configure PKCE in KeyCloak server?
I am looking for a way to configure the PKCE in KeyCloak server. Is there anyway that we can force Keycloak server to use PKCE only while authentication.
I tried reading the keycloak documentation. I found something related to it but not firm.

This can be configured in the Advanced tab on Client Details.

Clients > {your-client} > Advanced
Under Advanced settings select the Proof Key for Code Exchange Code Challenge Method and set it to S256

